# disable panning on map with mouse

Tags: javascript, amcharts, ammap

I have discovered how to remove the controls for panning and zooming.  I also found the property to stop zooming in on mouse clicks.  How can I prevent the user from panning the map with the mouse?

Comment: How do you remove the controls for panning and zooming?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set `map.dragMap = false;`

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of map instantiation expanded with all options related to the functionality mentioned in the question, both the ones already found and the one OP asked for. The option that answers the question is `"dragMap": false`:

```js
var map = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "map",
    "theme": "light",
    "dataProvider": {
        "map": "worldLow",
        "getAreasFromMap": true
    },
    "dragMap": false,                // disables map dragging/panning
    "zoomOnDoubleClick": false,      // disables zoom on double click
    "zoomControl": {
        "zoomControlEnabled": false, // disables +/- zoom control
        "panControlEnabled": false   // disables pan controls (default)
    },
    "areasSettings": {
        "autoZoom": false,           // disables zoom when click on area
        "selectable": true           // determines whether an area is selectable - i.e. clicking on an area/country changes its color
    }
});
```

Comment: This might or might not solve the OP's issue, perhaps consider adding some explanation to the answer might give better insight.